# Sql Count query (Avoid "-" entries)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the Total number of Farmers in a column but i want my query to avoid "-" in

the column how can i do that.Instead Of Null values my table have "-".

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(FarmerName) AS 
Total_Number_Of_Farmers FROM try", con);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question but will this not work?

```
SELECT COUNT(FarmerName) AS Total_Number_Of_Farmers 
FROM try
WHERE FarmerName <> '-'
```

or

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(FarmerName) AS Total_Number_Of_Farmers FROM try WHERE FarmerName <> '-'", con);
```

If you need to do it for multiple columns at once (as requested in comments), the following should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(NULLIF(DistrictName,'-'))) AS Unique_DistrictNames 
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT(NULLIF(TownName,'-'))) AS Unique_TownNames 
FROM try
```

`NULLIF(a, b)` returns `NULL` if a and b are equal. `COUNT(a)` only counts values that are `NOT NULL`, so this way you should be counting only values that are not `'-'`.

Comment: I assure you that the other one is slower and it will fail if a farmer has a double-barrelled name..

Comment: ok if i want to count "-" in all the columns how will i do that? adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select count (*) from try where DistrictName = '-' OR TownName = '-'",con) but this is not working properly

Comment: are those the only 2 columns? If so, that should be working. Presumably you still need `OR FarmerName = '-'`

Comment: yes that worked  i want to count ditinct values excluding "-" how can i change this query to perform that select Count(DISTINCT(DistrictName))  AS Unique_DistrictNames  , Count(DISTINCT(TownName)) AS Unique_TownNames from try

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(FarmerName) AS Total_Number_Of_Farmers 
FROM try
WHERE FarmerName not like '%-%'
```